# Odoo | Error on Product Creation. State in Archived

Tags: python, odoo, product, stock, odoo-14

When I creating Product OR Product Variant then it is by default in Archived and showing me this warning message when I am saving it.

Invalid fields:

1. Name
2. Product Type
3. Product Category
4. Unit of Measure
5. Purchase Unit of Measure
6. Sales Order Line
7. Message for Sales Order Line
8. Purchase Order Line Warning
9. Message for Purchase Order Line

What is wrong in the database or configuration? Can anyone help?

[Odoo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzFcA.png)

[Odoo Product Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW2WG.png)

Comment: You need to fill some required field .Because that field are written by required and if you don't fill , you can't save and get error.

Comment: I know about that it is mandatory to set but normally while product creation it is not in Archived and default fields are set up. But right now it is messed up, what is this
Message of Sale Order Line
Message of Purchase Order Line?

Comment: You used enterprise or community?You have any custom module for product?

Comment: Yes I have custom Module and it is causing an error. I have corrected it. Solved now !!